# Why Does the R Interpreter Continue to Excute Code After an Error?

Tags: r

When I send a block of R code to the interpreter in RStudio (or Tinn-R or any other environment) if there's an error on line 1, lines 2, 3, 4 ... still execute. Why is this the default behavior? It seems contrary to how most programming languages work and dangerous in the sense that if line 1 produces an error it could alter what subsequent lines of code do. It's particularly bad in long scripts that have a lot of printed output because you can miss an error message amidst the regular output. Is there a reason, either logical or historical, why R works this way? And is it possible to change this behavior and ensure that the interpreter will stop upon encountering an error?

Answer (score 4):

Consider some R code with an error:

```
print("starting")
b+sdlkfjsflkj
print("hello world")
```

If I select this code and copy it into the interpreter, as you describe it will continue past the error:

```
> print("starting")
[1] "starting"
> b+sdlkfjsflkj
Error: object 'b' not found
> print("hello world")
[1] "hello world"
```

A simple solution that causes it to stop at the error would be storing it in a script and running it with `source`:

```
source("play.R")
[1] "starting"
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'b' not found
```

If you want to keep working interactively, another option would be placing the code inside a block. If I copy the following code into R interactively...

```
{
print("starting")
b+sdlkfjsflkj
print("hello world")
}
```

... then I get the following output:

```
[1] "starting"
Error: object 'b' not found
```

Comment: Running code between {brackets} has the desired behavior. One thing to note is that it does change R's printing behavior, e.g. `{head(df)}` will not print the first few lines of a data frame, but instead requires an explicit print call. Not a bad thing, that's typical in most languages, just something to be aware of.